# Binding function to older/newer button in Gmail

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to bind a particular function to the Newer/Older buttons inside Gmail inbox.

The html for these two buttons is as follows:

```
<div id=":i0" class="T-I J-J5-Ji amD T-I-awG T-I-ax7 T-I-Js-IF L3" role="button" tabindex="0" data-tooltip="Newer" aria-label="Newer" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><span class="amF">&nbsp;</span><img class="amI T-I-J3" src="images/cleardot.gif" alt=""></div>


<div id=":hs" class="T-I J-J5-Ji amD T-I-awG T-I-ax7 T-I-Js-Gs L3" role="button" tabindex="0" data-tooltip="Older" aria-label="Older" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><span class="amF">&nbsp;</span><img class="amJ T-I-J3" src="images/cleardot.gif" alt=""></div>
```

I tried various methods like:

```
$('span.Di div.T-I').one('click', function(){
        console.log('Hey');
});
```

or

```
$('span.Di').find('div.T-I').addClass('.class-name');
$('.class-name').click(function(){
    console.log('hey');
});
```

Now, this works when I click the button the first time, however on subsequent clicks, it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`.one(` functions only executes once, try replacing it with `.on(`

```
$('span.Di div.T-I').on('click', function(){
```

And in your second bit of code, change it to:

```
$('span.DI').find('div.T-I').addClass('.class-name');
$('.class-name').click(function(){
    console.log('hey');
});
```

You had a typo (missing `'` before the closing bracket) in: `$('span.DI)`.

Comment: hey Daniel, I realised the typo. Nevertheless, both methods aren't working. In the second method, the class gets added only the first time and not after the second click. I think it may have something to do with the Loading part of Gmail. So I'll have to call the function after the view has finished loading.

Comment: I'm guessing that Gmail is rerendering the buttons and since the click listener only gets added once, it never triggers again. Try something like `$('body').on('click', 'span.Di div.T-I', Fn);`